# Are massage creams containing paraben bad for health?

Tags: side-effects, topical-cream-gel, preservitives, cosmetics

Are massage creams containing paraben bad for health?

For example, I see that the [free-up massage cream](https://www.google.com/search?q=Freeup+Massage+Cream) contains methylparaben: should I use a [paraben-free massage cream](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0008E8KC8) instead of it?

I read on http://www.livestrong.com/article/21581-dangers-methylparaben/ :

> Methylparaben is widely used as a preservative in women's cosmetics, such as skin creams and deodorants. This compound has been found intact within breast cancer tissues. Some researchers suggest that methylparaben may increase risk of breast cancer, or accelerate the growth of these tumors.

but there is no link to any scientific study.

{1} reports:

> Methyl paraben is not carcinogenic or mutagenic. It is not teratogenic or embryotoxic and is negative in the uterotrophic assay. The mechanism of cytotoxic action of parabens may be linked to mitochondrial failure dependent on induction of membrane permeability transition accompanied by the mitochondrial depolarization and depletion of cellular ATP through uncoupling of oxidative phosphorylation. Parabens are reported to cause contact dermatitis reactions in some individuals on cutaneousl exposure. Parabens have been implicated in numerous cases of contact sensitivity associated with cutaneous exposure; however, the mechanism of this sensitivity is unknown. Sensitization has occurred when medications containing parabens have been applied to damaged or broken skin. Allergic reactions to ingested parabens have been reported, although rigorous evidence of the allergenicity of ingested paraben is lacking.

but the study is 15-year-old.

The [US FDA seems fine with parabens](http://www.fda.gov/Cosmetics/ProductsIngredients/Ingredients/ucm128042.htm) but don't cite any scientific study:

> Are parabens safe as they’re used in cosmetics? Are they linked to
>   breast cancer or other health problems?
>
> FDA scientists continue to review published studies on the safety of
>   parabens. At this time, we do not have information showing that
>   parabens as they are used in cosmetics have an effect on human health.
>   Here are some of the questions we are considering:
>
> - What do published studies show about the possible hazards of parabens, and on the effects of parabens on human health? For example,
>     do experimental findings with various parabens also happen in real
>     life?
> - What are the hazards and risks of not using parabens? If we stop using parabens to protect cosmetics and consumers from harmful
>     bacteria, are there safer alternatives for preservatives?
> - If there are paraben-related health effects that are scientifically supported and documented, how do these effects relate to the use of
>     parabens in cosmetics?
> - Do the different kinds of parabens act the same or differently in our bodies?
>
> FDA will continue to evaluate new data in this area. If we determine
>   that a health hazard exists, we will advise the industry and the
>   public, and will consider the agency’s legal options under the
>   authority of the FD&C Act to protect the health and welfare of
>   consumers.

---

References:

- {1} Soni, M. G., Stephen L. Taylor, N. A. Greenberg, and G. A. Burdock. "Evaluation of the health aspects of methyl paraben: a review of the published literature." Food and Chemical Toxicology 40, no. 10 (2002): 1335-1373. https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=3137612844209117541&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22 ; http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0278691502001072 ; http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0278-6915(02)00107-2